# SFDX and travis ConnectedAPP

Tags: salesforcedx

When doing the trailhead module it makes all connections using a dev Edition, when using a production environment that has the devhub. Can the connected app can be created in a sandbox or does it need to be in prod? I would like to test some functionality, making the ci/cd from git to a specific sandbox and not getting stuff to prod environment. Is this possible?

Comment: The connected app needs to be created in the devhub but the actual ci/cd wont need to point to a production env. You have flexibility there.

Comment: @ZackWalton To be pedantic, the Connected App needs to be created in *an* org, it need not be production. However, that org should be a "permanent" org to avoid losing the connected app when the org is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

> the connected app can be created in a sandbox or need to be in prod?

The connected app has to be created in the DevHub, which typically will be Prod.

> I would like to test some functionality, making the ci/cd from git to a specific sandbox and not getting stuff to prod environment. Is this possible?

Yes, this is possible. Just by creating the connected app in Prod does not signify that your CI/CD process will build/deploy in Production. The connected app here provides a *headless* way of authorizing the CI user to be able to create Scratch Orgs, run CLI commands and perform the CI/CD process on behalf of the CI User. Excerpt from the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_travis_ci/sfdx_travis_ci_connected_app):

> However, you’ll need a way to manage the authorization process, because you’re not there to personally log in when your CI or build automation job runs.
>
> ...
>
> Basically, for our purposes, it enables your headless process to connect to the Dev Hub and execute Salesforce CLI commands.

Comment: It need not be the dev hub, but it should be an org that is "permanent", such as a Developer Edition org, and definitely not a trial org or sandbox.

Comment: It may not be Prod (and thus used *typically*), but it has to be DevHub, right?

Comment: It can be any org, you just need to have the consumer id and secret. It need not be your dev hub or your production. For example, I could create an app in *my* dev org, and give it to you, and you could use it. This is how connected apps are designed to work.

Comment: Connected apps are fine. And you will need the consumer id/secret from the Org where you will want to login. But if you have to use it in context for CI/CD using SFDX, then I would imagine you will need the Connected app to be created in Dev Hub, as you will want to login to Dev Hub say to be able to create Scratch Orgs for your CI process.

Comment: Connected Apps authenticate the application, not the user. It doesn't matter where the app is, as the user will log in to whichever org they want using that app.

Comment: I may not be following this, but are you saying that if I have a connected app A in my sandbox and I get the access token from sandbox, I can still access the app in Production? I may be wrong here, but I don't think it works that way.

Comment: You're confusing access token with consumer id/secret. For example, if you go in the Data Loader, you can use OAuth to log in. The Connected App for the Data Loader is hosted in another org (presumably org62), yet you can use that Connected App to connect to any org you want to. Once you use the Data Loader in an org, it creates a copy of the Connected App in that org. Administrators can use that to revoke access/block/etc, but the consumer id and secret will not be revealed in any org except the original host org.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I tryed to do what you said, create the connected app in a different org than the dev hub, but when I try to get the JWT if I connect to the sandbox where the connected app is I get success but an error when I try to create the scratch org, "You do not have access to the [ScratchOrgInfo] Object". Okay, when I try to connect to production, where my devHub is, I get an error saying Invalid_grant - user hasn't approved this consumer. Is there anything I can do to overcome that issue?

Comment: @RafaelCunha The first authentication worked, as I stated it would. Your problem is that you haven't set up a Permission Set to give yourself access to the relevant objects (see [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm)). The second error was because the app was set to "users must authorize" instead of admin pre-authorization.

Comment: @sfdcfox, okay in the first the deal is I am not in a devhub environment so I can add these permissions to myself. In the second the app policy is admin approved users, but I am not sysadmin in prod, do I need a sysAdmin user? I am afraid I will not be able to get this user easily in prod environment, but there I have access to the sfdx objects even with my user. Thanks

Comment: @RafaelCunha You can have your admin configure a Permission Set for you, you don't need to *be* the admin. This is how we're set up in our prod org.

Comment: @sfdcfox, but a permission set in prod can add access to a connected app that is in a sandbox?

Comment: @RafaelCunha The permission set is for your user, not for the app. The connected app can work with any org you can log in to, and a copy is automatically created in that org when you log in with that app.